# How to check if the rotation is locked on Android

Tags: android

I have an app, and I want my app to respect the rotation honer. But how to check if the rotation is locked on Android? Programmatically of course :)

=================

Thanks [imran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202025/imran-khan) for answer. I put it here again because I can not find anything about DEFAULT_ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, and also there is not need to change user-permission if you just want to read a system setting. Cheers!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#getInt(android.content.ContentResolver, java.lang.String)

int str = Settings.System.getInt(Context.getContentResolver(),
    Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, DEFAULT_ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check rotation if locked or not by using System Setting as:

```
   int str = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),                                    
             Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 
             DEFAULT_ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION); 

   if(str==1) 
   {
      // rotation is Unlocked
   } else {
      // rotation is Locked
   }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Please remove the part about the user-permission because it is not required if I just want to read the value.

Comment: @dongshengcn Do you know how to use the permissions to set the locking?

Comment: I used this example and no perms were required: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636464/find-out-if-device-orientation-is-locked-detect-if-auto-rotate-is-enabled-disab

Answer (score 8):

ρяσѕρєя K solution works, but this reply is a pretier and fixed solution:

```
boolean isOrientationEnabled;

try {
    isOrientationEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),                                    
        Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION) == 1;
} catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
    isOrientationEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: What's prettier about this? This is merely not using the if statement and the default value.

Comment: First: the if statement contains the same comment in then and else blocks. Second: ContentResolver can be got easily just calling getContentResolver() if the code is executed in an activity. Third: the exception isn't being handle. Fourht: Is better setting a default value handling the exception. Fifth: no write permission are needed is you are just reading.

Comment: Great work. I dislike adding permissions and this answer is exactly what I like. Thanks!

Comment: This is a better answer. Why would permissions need to be added for this!?