# Find out if device orientation is locked (Detect if auto-rotate is enabled/disabled)

Tags: android, android-orientation

How can I find out is device's screen orientation locked? I am using OrientationEventListener to trigger some actions inside my app which I would like to disable if user has his screen locked.

I know I can usually can orientation like this but how to find out is this locked orientation:

```
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // It's portrait
    } else {
        // It's landscape
    }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Auto Rotate is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Auto Rotate is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to detect it when the "screen rotation" is enabled or disabled? I'm looking for a way likes broadcast.

Answer (score -2):

You can check the orientation in runtime like:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Kristo, but this doesn't give info is screen locked.

Comment: Maybe i missunderstood your question because it is not really clear of what you need. I thought you wanted to check the type of orientation. anyway happy coding.