# Android set orientation

Tags: android, orientation, sensors

I have an oddball android device which has no gravity sensors, and on that device,
my "set orientaion" function does nothing.   On all other devices, including some
without sensors, the following works fine.

```
        Activity act = AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
    int newo = portrait 
        ?   (reverse
                ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT
                : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        :   (reverse
                ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE
                : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    act.setRequestedOrientation(
            newo
```

is there some additional API that can lock the screen orientation?  Some
other apps successfully change the screen orientation.

Comment: Is portrait vs landscape not working?  Or just portrait/reverse portrait?

Comment: in my app, no rotation occurs.  Using a 3'rd party rotator app, reverse landscape doesn't work, but the other 3 orientations work.

Comment: Presence of sensors has nothing to do with orientation support. The default android screen has 3 axes mapped to the display panel / device body. `setRequestedOrientation()`  should work, unless the device's manufacturer has provided a really poor implementation of this API.

Comment: Have you checked if the orientation on that device is locked? May that be a device, that never changes orientation (if there's anything like that)? Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636464/find-out-if-device-orientation-is-locked-detect-if-auto-rotate-is-enabled-disab

Comment: You could also check the answer from "Paul", he describes different orientation constants for different API versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button

Answer (score 3):

Check orientation

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

How to lock orientation?

```
public class OrientationUtils {
private OrientationUtils() {}

/** Locks the device window in landscape mode. */
public static void lockOrientationLandscape(Activity activity) {
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

/** Locks the device window in portrait mode. */
public static void lockOrientationPortrait(Activity activity) {
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

/** Allows user to freely use portrait or landscape mode. */
public static void unlockOrientation(Activity activity) {
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}

}
```

Comment: this looks like exactly what I am already doing, which has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

How about `android:screenOrientation="locked"`. This will lock the orientation to its current rotation `(From API 18)`